# Do various job offers on Stack Overflow depend on user reputation? How does it work?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, reputation

Do companies advertising job offers on users' Stack Overflow page have access to Stack Overflow data like reputation, badges, etc.? Can a user with 10k+ reputation see better job offers compared to user with reputation in 3 digits.

How does the job offer targeting work?

Comment: Reputation is the reflection of trust community imparts on you. Some user earned reputation through writing questions only. I don't think this will effect jobs advertisements although you can use search as well.

Comment: Personally if I was hiring I would be more interested in seeing a portfolio of projects you have worked on as opposed to your reputation on here. I also have seen users deliberately farm reputation that I would look up on negatively. Also if your rep was really high on here I would question how much of your time working for me would actually be productive time as opposed to active on this forum.

Comment: I cleaned up the acerbic comments towards SO and the advertising system. You don't get to 'not care' and take potshots with frankly rude accusations of malicious intent at the same time.

Comment: @axawire As someone with a fair bit of rep myself, I agree entirely. Most of my rep is from a couple of answers that, while I think they're good (or I wouldn't have written them), aren't particularly demonstrative of my programming ability. I'd rather show off some of my cool projects; at least those are slightly representative.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not a developer on the team and I don't have that much rep, but my co-worker and I see the same job results in SO based on keyword search.  So I believe the answer is No.

However, if you are reaching out to developers and pay via the careers site (as a hiring manager / employer) yes you can then filter based on reputation.  I'm not sure about badges because I had an account through the SO services allowing me to look to hire individuals and I remember seeing filters for rep but not badges.

I could do something like give me all users living in a certain area that had a reputation range from x to y.

Comment: "I don't have that much rep"--Said the user in the top 2% overall.

Comment: @BoogaRoo - But I've been on the site for over 8 years...so it's all relative.

Comment: A filter by tag badges might be an interesting feature to have for hiring managers

Comment: @JonH If it were all relative and I've been on the site for half as long as you I'd have 13k rep, alas... I do not... :(

Comment: @NickA - da people dey like me ehh - dey just like me...Viva JonH...Viva JonH!

Comment: @NickA Well, it probably was easier to get rep earlier in the site's history. I suspect that someone who has been here 4 years would have less than half the reputation of someone who has been here 8 years even if their post histories are similar in quantity and quality.

Comment: @DavidZ I have no doubt that some older answers get answers due to votes over, but it was more meant in jest, I'm sure if I made more of an attempt to answer questions I'm sure I'd have higher rep

Comment: nah, it's much easier now due to there being far more questions per day.

Comment: @DavidZ There's no real correlation between age of account and reputation. I have seen lots of 8-year accounts that have less than a thousand rep, and I have seen several users who have nearly maxed out reputation every day over a membership of 6 months to a year.

Comment: @TylerH that doesn't prove there isn't a correlation, it just proves that there is no general rule (because there are counterexamples).

Comment: @Nemo Yes, I don't have any SEDE query results or graph handy to show the plot of all users reputation vs their account age to show that there is really no strong correlation.

Comment: @NickA relative != proportional

Comment: You do have that much rep.